# How to start a new activity from the current in expandableListView's setOnChildCliclkListener?

Tags: expandablelistview

```
expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            String headername = (String) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getGroup(groupPosition);
            String childname = (String) parent.getExpandableListAdapter().getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);

            Log.d("Parent name",headername);
            Log.d("Child name", childname);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ViewActivity.this,ShowActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Parent",headername);
            intent.putExtra("Child",childname);
            intent.putExtra("Path",myPath);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: please edit your question and properly indent the code

Comment: Please add a full description of the problem. Why you are "unable to start a new activity", any error or stack trace? What happens?

Comment: Please add relevant tags, e.g. `android`, otherwise this question may not get a lot of attention.

Answer (score 0):

Just use ActivityName.this.startActivity() and that would call the required intent.